# How to delete all posts from my PostgreSQL table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm building a Rails app in which one of the functions is that the user can write journal entries and save them. I'd like to remove every journal entry from the respective PostgreSQL table they're in. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
# assuming your journal entries are a model named Entry
Entry.find(:all).each { |e| e.destroy! }
```

Probably not the most efficient way, but it will do what you ask.

Comment: There is a [shortcut](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) for that. I don't think you can do any better if you want all the callbacks executed.

Comment: It's always safer not to bypass callbacks, unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about callbacks and just want to delete everything in the table, you can use [`delete_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete_all):

```
JournalEntry.delete_all
```

If you *do* want callbacks executed, you can use [`destroy_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all):

```
JournalEntry.destroy_all
```